# Height broken for UIDatePicker in UITableViewCell in static cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uidatepicker

I'm trying to put a UIDatePicker into a UITableViewCell which is opened/closed by clicking on the cell above it. The picker seems to be rendering all wrong. Firstly, here is the related code from the UITableView class:

```
// Determines if the date picker should be shown
var editingDate: Bool = false

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1 { // Picker cell
        if !self.editingDate {
            return 0
        }
    }

    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0 { // Date cell
        self.editingDate = !self.editingDate
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 1)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

The table in the storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

I have set the Table Cell to a custom height of 219 in the storyboard. Below is an animated GIF of what happens when I currently click the date field. Sorry for the terrible quality.

[image: animation]

I noticed that we can see from the animated gif above that the cell background becomes transparent (not white) which means the Content View of the cell is not stretching to the full height. I wonder why that could be?

**Edit:** Here is the constraints used for the DatePicker:

[image: constraints]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use static cells, you can specify the height of the cell holding the picker in the storyboard editor and your code could look like this:

```
if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1 && !editingDate) { // Picker cell
        return 0
} 

return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

**Update**

Replace:

```
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 1)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
```

With:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't seem to work. I just noticed that we can see from the animated gif above that the cell background becomes transparent (not white) which means the Content View of the cell is not stretching to the full height. I wonder why that could be?

Comment: If you are using static cells, you can specify the height of the cell holding the picker in the storyboard editor and then you could change your code a bit. I'll update my answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the code in my question above as i'm using static cells and have the custom height set in the storyboard. I also added a new picture of the constraints. Unfortunately the issue still persists..

Comment: Try using:
tableView.beginUpdates()  and                                                  
tableView.endUpdates()
in stead of:
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 1)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

Comment: That worked! Do you want to update your answer with the code so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AutoLayout?

If so try pinning your DatePicker by the cell's edges in IB by CTRL-dragging from it to the cell. After all 4 edges have been pinned give it another try.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it did make the DatePicker more centered but it didn't fix the issue. I was unable to CTRL-drag to the cell, but instead to the Content View within the cell. Also, the app now throws the following warning: `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.`

Comment: Yes, you are right. The contentView of the cell is the view you can drag your constraints to. But the error you are talking about means your constraints are not ok. Can you post a screenshot for those?

Comment: I've updated the question to include the constraints and also the full warning. I tried deleting the constraint that its complaining about (top) and the warning goes away but still doesn't work.